# How to write Mathjax formulas inside JSON and put into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json, mathjax

My JSON file contain a Mathjax formula:

The Mathjax formula is not displayed correctly, it is displayed as it is written. When I put that formula in HTML directly, it works fine, and displays the formula as it should be. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

```js
const currentQuestion = {
  "question": "\\[x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}.\\]",
  "choice1": "kw",
  "choice2": "k22",
  "choice3": "k3",
  "answer": 3
}

const choices = document.querySelectorAll(".choice-text");

choices.forEach((choice) => {
  const number = choice.dataset['number'];
  choice.innerHTML = currentQuestion['choice' + number];
});
```

```html
<h2 id="question">Koji je odgovor na sledeca pitanja</h2>
<div class="choice-container">
  <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
  <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice 1</p>
</div>
<div class="choice-container">
  <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
  <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">Choice 2</p>
</div>
<div class="choice-container">
  <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
  <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">Choice 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and other code. Where do you set the question for example?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will add the whole code.

Comment: See my updated answer. You need the correct files

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Ignore the localStorage warnings

I got the math script file url from the [manual](https://www.mathjax.org/#gettingstarted)

NOTE: The JSON needs to have the backslashes escaped:

```js
const questions = JSON.parse(`[{"question":"\\\\[x = {-b \\\\pm \\\\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\\\over 2a}.\\\\]","choices":["kw","k22","k3"],"answer":2},{"question":"\\\\[x = {-b \\\\pm \\\\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\\\over 2a}.\\\\]","choices":["kw","k22","k3"],"answer":2},{"question":"\\\\[x = {-b \\\\pm \\\\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\\\over 2a}.\\\\]","choices":["kw","k22","k3"],"answer":2}]`)

const letters  = "ABCDEF";
const html = questions.map((question,i) => {
  const choices = question.choices.map((choice,i) => `<p class="choice-prefix">${letters[i]}</p>
  <p class="choice-text" data-number="${(i+1)}">${choice}</p>`).join("");
  return `<h3>${question.question}</h3><div class="choice-container">${choices}</div>`
}).join("")

document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = html;

console.log(JSON.stringify(questions))
```

```html
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
<h2>Koji je odgovor na sledeca pitanja</h2>
<div  id="questions"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, the code works when it is directly in HTML, but what I need is to be inside JSON file, because, I have a lot of questions, and this is just an example. So this should be inside JSON and to be displayed properly: "question": "\\[x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}.\\]",
  "choice1": "kw",
  "choice2": "k22",
  "choice3": "k3",
  "answer": 3

Comment: I do not undestand. I use the object your JSON creates and insert the code into an html element. What are your expectations here?

Comment: The problem is that somehow formulas doesn't transfers as a formula but as a plain text from JSON to HTML.

Comment: That is another thing. You need to have the JSON correctly escaped. See update where I parse from a JSON entity

Comment: For some reason, when I escape backslashes, it only displays the formula text, not the formula itself.

Comment: See I escape with 4 slashes